# Merging various sed commands is not working well

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to compress an html file with following steps using sed command:

Remove comments by `sed -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba'`

Remove blank lines by: `sed '/^\s*$/d'`

Remove leading spaces by: `sed 's/^\s*//g'`

Remove trailing spaces by: `sed 's/\s*$//g'`

Merging all lines into one by: `sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n//g'`

Above commands have been taken from different sources on the web including Stackoverflow answers.

When I chain above commands using pipe (`|`) operator, it works very well. However, when I try to use a single sed command, some functions are not working:

```
sed -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba; /^\s*$/d; s/^\s*//g; s/\s*$//g; :a; N; $!ba; s/\n//g'
```

The comments are not removed and the blank spaces are also not removed, though all the lines are getting merged into one.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: `.*?` in the very first sed command is undefined behavior in an ERE (as you're using with `-r`) and will not do in sed what it would do in a tool that supports PCREs so the script is broken out the gate. Don't try to use sed for this, use an XML parser and if you can't get one of those and are restricted to mandatory POSIX tools then use awk.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

> Where is the problem

The problem is that some commands are intended to work on each line of the file, while `N` appends the next line into pattern space and `b` modifies script execution flow. This causes further commands to be executed only on the end of the file, with no more lines available to read.

Note: to parse XML files use XML parser, not sed.

> how can it be solved?

It can be solved by "programming" - analyzing the purpose of the sed commands one by one and analyzing the intended flow of each sed script and rewriting the code that will work as intended.

Comment: Can there be a single sed command that can  do all these steps?